# How to get list of items in an entity using DiscoveryService in Dynamics CRM 2016?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to get the list of contacts using the DiscoveryServiceClient in CRM 2016 on-prem

I added service reference and created an object, but I am not sure on what method I should be using to get the list of Entity items

```
                    CRMService.DiscoveryServiceClient client = new CRMService.DiscoveryServiceClient();
                    client.Open();
                    var query = new QueryExpression();
                    query.EntityName = "Contact";

                    query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet { AllColumns = true };
                    var coll = client.RetrieveMultiple(query);

                    Console.WriteLine("Retrieved {0} entities", coll.Entities.Count());
                    foreach (var item in coll.Entities)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Contact: " + item);
                    }
                    client.Close();
```

When I used the above code it says

> DiscoveryServiceClient does not contain a definition for
>   RetrieveMultiple

I also tried using the below code

```
QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
                    qe.EntityName = "contact";
                    qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet();
                    qe.ColumnSet.Columns.Add("emailaddress1");
                    EntityCollection ec = organizationProxy.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
 foreach (Entity act in ec.Entities)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("account email:" + act["emailaddress1"]);
                    }
```

This loads fine, but all values are null inside the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a special need for you to use the DiscoveryServiceClient?
If this is a job or so, you should/could use the IOrganizationService to retrieve your EntityCollection.

Here is a little Link, that might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328029(v=crm.8)

Comment: thanks I tried that too, but values are coming up as null. I've updated the question with details now

Comment: is the recieving Collection empty? you can check that with:

ec.Entities.Count

you should also use: act.getAttributeValue<string>("emailaddress2"); Origin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.getattributevalue?view=dynamics-general-ce-9